# HTML label is not attached to input when added dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a checkbox with a label like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="box1"/>
<label for="box1">Option 1</label>
```

This renders as expected ,and has the additional bonus that you can click on the label's text to check/uncheck the checkbox.

If I dynamically append more checkboxes and labels with jquery like this:

```
var optionsPanel = $("#optionsInnerWrapper");
    for(var i = 0; i < allOptions.length; i++)
    {
        optionsPanel.append("<div style='padding:2px;''><input id='box"+i+"' class='filterType' type='checkbox' value='"+allOptions[i]+"'><label for='box'"+i+"''>"+allOptions[i]+"</label></div>");
    }
```

Everything renders ok, but clicking the label will not check or uncheck the appropiate checkbox. why is this, and can i achieve this effect in another way?

Comment: You have an extra pair of single quotes in `<label for='box'"+i+"''>"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jquery code isn't right.

```
        optionsPanel.append("<div style='padding:2px;''><input id='box"+i+"' class='filterType' type='checkbox' value='"+allOptions[i]+"'><label for='box"+i+"'>"+allOptions[i]+"</label></div>");
```

What did i change?

You had too much ' here: `<label for='box'"+i+"''>"+allOptions[i]+"</label>`

`<label for='box'"+i+"''>"+allOptions[i]+"</label>`

`<label for='box"+i+"'>"+allOptions[i]+"</label>`

Answer (score 3):

```
"'><label for='box'"+i+"''>"
```

should be

```
"'><label for='box"+i+"'>"
```

There are extra single quotes in the original.